# How to find the value of an XPATH with a tab already open with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

I just got into web scraping but every question or tutorial haves you open a new tab with python. The website I would like to use is called nitro typer and I already know how to get the XPATH. The issue is I want to be able to get the value of that path using an already opened tab. I have only used selenium.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "a tab already open" ? Do you mean something you already have *manually* opened? mind sharing some code?

Comment: it seems like job rather for some browser extension, not for Python.